# Testing outlook plugins

Tags: testing, outlook, automated-tests

What tools are good to do automated UI testing of Outlook plugins? We are developing plugin in VB 6.0. We are using Microsoft's UI Automation framework. Any best practices regarding the framework? Any other tools which should be explored?

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard Windows API controls in your plugin and you like Python, you may use [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) - Gui Automation with Python

I have a positive experience in the testing of several Spam Filter plugins for MS Outlook with pywinauto.